# AWS: pointing A record to load balancer on A record causes incoming email to stop functioning

Tags: dns-servers, amazon-aws, amazon-ec2, route53

I have a webserver running on an EC2.
On that EC2 I'm receiving email.

I've created a load balancer (ELB) directing traffic to EC2

In route 53:

- UPDATED `A` record for `example.com` to point to ELB
- UPDATED `CNAME` record for `@.example.com` to point to ELB

I kept the following records:

- `MX` record: `*.example.com` to point to 10 mail.domain.com
- `CNAME` record: `mail.example.com` points to EC2

In this setup the load balancer is working, directing traffic to EC2.

However, if I send an email to `user@example.com` it doesn't reach EC2.

I'm pretty sure, I can set it up with a subdomain pointing to the loadbalancer, but I would prefer to have my main domain main point to the loadbalancer.

Answer (score 2):

`MX` record: `*.example.com` matches everything but the naked (no subdomain) domain. So no `MX` for `example.com`. Aparently a friendly MTA will try the A record, which used to work for me, since it pointed to the EC2 handling my email.

Long story short. Removed the `*.` from the `MX` record and it worked.

I hope this will save someone a couple of hours of trying stuff...

Comment: Kudos for solving it yourself... but note that you have a second misconfiguration that also works, by accident.  The target of an MX record is not technically allowed to be a CNAME.  `MX 10 foo.example.com.` requires that `foo.example.com.` is NOT a CNAME, but an actual A record with the IP address of the host that accepts the mail. See [RFC-2181 Section 10.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2181#section-10.3).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Michael! Will fix that too!